# Add Dropbox or other Links in Windows Explorer 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1, dropbox, onedrive

Is there a way to add Dropbox (or Google Drive, Box, etc) to the Desktop area in Windows Explorer? In-between `SkyDrive` and `Chris`?

Skydrive is more or less forced on you in 8.1, but it remains unused for many valid reasons. I'd like to bring the other options to the forefront if possible (Maybe even replace Skydrive if possible).

***Edit:*** I guess, after a comment, I could expand this to say `Can ANY link be placed in this area? Perhaps also removing Skydrive and Libraries since they are useless (for me)?`

I am referring to the left pane, under Desktop. I'm constantly going to a few key locations and would love to add the important stuff there.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you can set it between SkyDrive and Chris but you can definitely have DropBox installed and set up to point to C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\DropBox and DropBox Folder will appear on your Desktop.

Comment: @Darius That much I know, but I'd like to save a few clicks since I go into Dropbox often. I guess the question could be expanded to `Can ANY links be placed in this area`, since there are different links at different places (Work, home) that I use often and would like "close at hand" but aren't Skydrive or Libraries.

Comment: You CAN remove SkyDrive, but it does involve some registry editing, so at least that is one less icon on "Desktop" that you don't have to deal with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace OneDrive with Dropbox in Windows 8.1](http://superuser.com/questions/739478/replace-onedrive-with-dropbox-in-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

I know this only answers part of your question but you can remove SkyDrive by editing the Registry. Change:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{8E74D236-7F35-4720-B138-1FED0B85EA75}\ShellFolder\Attributes
```

from `f08004d` to `f09004d` and reboot.

You can remove Libraries by right-clicking and deselecting *Show Libraries*

This comes from [PC Pro](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2013/12/04/how-to-remove-skydrive-from-the-windows-8-1-explorer/)

Answer (score 1):

When in desktop mode, open your web browser and go to dropbox.com and install the software from the website onto your computer instead of downloading the app from the microsoft app store. Once installed you will have the dropbox link where you want it on the left of the file explorer window and also the dropbox icon in the taskbar. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe id' be a good idea to put everything you need under Favourites, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIVRD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got some success on Windows 7 creating a directory symbolic link in my `Desktop` folder (i.e., the one under `%UserProfile%`).