# Possible to hide OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive is constantly running a process in the background and shows up in the leftmost pane of Windows Explorer. I use Google Drive so this is useless for me.

I just don't want to see it again. I understand it is built in to Windows 8.1 so its probably not possible to remove it completely (that would be ideal) but I would be happy with hiding it in some fashion

I've tried various solutions from Googling but none of them seem to work.

Anyone know if this is possible? It feels like I am trying to get rid of some piece of perfectly coded malware.

Comment: If you don't connect the connect to a Microaoft account then OneDrive can't sync

Comment: [This great answer](http://superuser.com/a/739486/156554) contains a detailed step-by-step guide on how to disable OneDrive in Windows 8.1. You can't uninstall OneDrive, but you can disable it so deeply, that you won't notice it at all (processes not running, no sync, icons gone etc.).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/sdinstall-sduninstalling/how-to-completely-disable-onedrive/b97a8336-62e7-476c-872c-3286c0a01cf6) removing OneDrive from Windows 8.1 is not possible, but the article does describe a way to disable the synchronization process.

It's probably also possible to hide the link from Windows Explorer.

Comment: How about including the steps described in the article?